# pagination without sending page number in URL using PHP & MS Sql Server

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, pagination

I am trying to implement pagination in my php web application. I am using sql server for DB.

In my web application, I have a list of clients displayed in html table. I have 2 buttons, **view all** and **disabled use**r.

My paging works fine for first attempt (I mean if I click '**view all**' or '**disabled user**' it shows first 10 records.). If I click on page no.2 paging link, URL shows `....com/?pagenum=2` and it shows next 11-20 records, but if when I again click **view all** or **disabled user** button, It doesn't shows first 10 records again, it stays to the same link `....com/?pagenum=2`.

How do I remove `?pagenum=2` from link when I again click **view all** or **show disable** button.

OR

Is there any way to do paging without sending page number into URL?

```
<input type="submit" id="view_all" class="theme-btn" value="View Current Users" name="view_all"/>
<input type="submit" class="theme-btn" value="Show Disabled Users" name="show_disabled"/>

$tsql = "SELECT COUNT(SubscriptionID) FROM Subscription";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $tsql);
$rowsReturned = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt);

    $numOfPages = ceil($rowsReturned[0]/$rowsPerPage);
    for($i = 1; $i<=$numOfPages; $i++)
    {
        $pageNum = "?pageNum=$i";
        print("<a href=$pageNum>$i</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;");
    }


$sql_query = "SELECT * FROM 
            (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ClientID) 
            AS ID, Name FROM Client);


if(isset($_GET['pageNum']))
{ 
    $highRowNum = $_GET['pageNum'] * $rowsPerPage;
    $lowRowNum = $highRowNum - $rowsPerPage + 1; 
    echo "high:$highRowNum, low:$lowRowNum";
}
else
{
    $lowRowNum = 1;
    $highRowNum = $rowsPerPage;
}

if(isset($_POST['show_disabled']) )
{   
    if(($emr!= 0) OR ($pas!= 0) OR ($pc!= 0))
    {   $flag=0;
    $sql_query = $sql_query . " WHERE Subscription.status = -1 AND (";
    GOTO C;
    }
}

if(isset($_POST['view_all']) )
{ 
    if(($emr!= 0) OR ($pas!= 0) OR ($pc!= 0))
    {   $flag=0;
    $sql_query = $sql_query . " WHERE (Subscription.status = 1 OR Subscription.status IS NULL) AND (";
    GOTO C;
    }


C: 

$sql_query = $sql_query. "AS TEST WHERE ClientID BETWEEN ? AND ? + 1"

$params = array(&$lowRowNum, &$highRowNum);
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql_query, $params, array( "Scrollable" => 'static' ));
if( $stmt === false) {die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );}   
GOTO A;
}


A:
if ($stmt) 
{
    $rows = sqlsrv_has_rows( $stmt ); //echo $rows;
    if ($rows === false)
        echo "</br><center>There is no data for this selection.</center><br />";
    else 
    {                   
        $rowsReturned = sqlsrv_num_rows( $stmt ); if ($rowsReturned === false) echo "Error in retrieveing row count.";
else echo "rowsReturned:".$rowsReturned." " ;

             echo "<table style='font-size: small; border-collapse: collapse;' id='clients'>            
            <th>SR NO</th>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>


       echo "<tr><td>".$sr."</td><td>". $row['ID']."</td><td>". $row['Name']."</td></tr>

        $sr++;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid you need to show some (the relevant) code. Without that nobody can help you.

Comment: I have added the code

Comment: it's a complicate contruction you've here, but I think this `$highRowNum = $rowsPerPage;` (in `if (isset['$_GET['pagenum']) ) else {}` )should be `$highRowNum = $numOfPages*$rowsPerPage;`

Comment: to remove `?pagenum=1`: I suppose you don't have an action defined in form?

Comment: please have a look at `LIMIT` for proper pagination: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select_limit.asp

Comment: Thanks, but LIMIT is MySQL clause, I am using MS SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery datatable plugin which will help you to apply pagination and search functionaliti...
Or you can go with ajax pagination.